# SAS If then else Statement with Do loop

Tags: sql, sas

I need to get a percentage for 75 values in 75 columns individually. And I want to use a do loop so I don't have to hard code it 75 times. There are some conditions so there will be a where statement.

I am not getting the do loop correctly but I am using the below to get a percentage

```
case when (SUM(t1.sam)) >0 then
  ((SUM(t1.sam))/(SUM(t1.sam_Threshold)))*100
else 0
end
```

I tried the below and its a bit better:

```
data test;
i_1=4;
i_2=8;
i_3=4;
i_4=8;
V_ANN_V_INSP=24;
run;

%macro loop(); 
%let numcols=4; 
proc sql;
create table test3 as
select V_ANN_V_INSP,
%do i=1 %to &numcols;
(i_&i/V_ANN_V_INSP)*100 as i_&i._perc
%if &i<&numcols %then %do;,
%end;
%end;
from test;
quit;
%mend; 
%loop();
```

Comment: Can you post more of your data step, and use the code tags to format your post please

Comment: Why did you role back the edits? You're new here, so you may be unfamiliar with the style, but code should be formatted, and it's unnecessary to include things like a request for help -- that's why we're here!

Comment: Hi @sasfrog, i dont really have a data step as I am new to sas (and also to the site). Hence I want to know if it can be done in SAS.

Answer (score 2):

CASE WHEN is a SQL statement, not a data step statement, so you can't use a DO loop there.  Depending on what you're doing exactly, there are a lot of possible solutions here.  Posting additional code would help to get a more precise answer, but I can give you a few suggestions.

First, take it into a data step.  Then you can use a do loop.

```
data want;
set have;
array nums sam1-sam75;
array denoms threshold1-threshold75;
array pct[75];
do _t = 1 to dim(nums);
  pct[_t]=nums[_t]/denoms[_t];
end;
run;
```

Second, if you need to do this in SQL for some reason, you can write out the SQL code either in a macro or in a data step in a pre-processing step.

```
%macro do_sql_st;
  %do _t = 1 to 75;
    case when (SUM(t1.sam&_t.)) >0 then
  ((SUM(t1.sam&_t.))/(SUM(t1.sam_Threshold&_t.)))*100
else 0
end
as pct&_t.
%end;
%mend do_sql_st;

proc sql;
select %do_sql_st from t1 where ... ;
quit;
```

These are not terribly flexible; unless you have very specifically named variables, they won't work as is.  You're more likely to want to do some sort of data step preprocessing I suspect, but that's very hard to explain without more detail as to how the variables are named (ie, if there is a relationship between them).

Comment: Hi Thanks Joe, thats great. basically what I am trying to do is below

Comment: Poc SQL;
   Create Table Work.Rsults AS 
   Select /* A_01 */ (case when (SUM(t1.SAM_A_01)) > 0 then (SUM(t1. SAM_A_01)) / (SUM(t1.SAM_V_INSP)))*100 else 0 end) AS A_01 FROM Results t1 
LEFT JOIN Org t2 ON   (t1.SAM_V_ID = t2.ORG_ID) 
LEFT JOIN Time t3 ON   (t1.SAM_T_ID = t3.TIM_ID) 
RIGHT JOIN T_ITEM t4 ON  (t1.SAM_A_01 = t4.T_NUM) AND 
(t1.SAM_A_02 = t4.T_NUM)
WHERE t3.T_LEVEL = 'DAY' 
AND t3.T_START_DATE = '1JAN2012'dt 
AND t3.T_END_DATE = '31DEC2012'dt 
AND t2.V_LEVEL = 'Internationl' 
AND t1.SAM_SUPP_PAID = 'N' 
AND t1.SAM_T_TYPE = 'Honda' 
AND t4.T_NUM = 1 
AND t4.T_TYPE = 'I';
QUIT;

Comment: The table 1 SAM has 75 columns, all as A_01 to A_75 for which i need to get percentage and the table 4 (T_Item) has colums T_NUM which also has 75 value which i need to match with the table 1 A_01 to A_75. I dont want to hard code all so am looking to reduce this. hope this makes sense

Comment: Don't put this kind of thing in comments. You can edit your question to add detail.